# Specify parameter for parent node in MvcSiteMapProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I have a sitemap like this:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Contact" controller="Home" action="Contact"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Project" controller="project" action="Index">
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Edit a Project" 
            controller="project" action="edit" preservedRouteParameters="id"/>
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

If I am on the edit page with a url like:

> localhost/project/edit/12de8b10-aaae-ebbb-cccc-00215e466552

I would like the breadcrumb link for Project to be this:

> localhost/project/?projectid=12de8b10-aaae-ebbb-cccc-00215e466552

Is this possible? I'm not sure what terms to use to describe that.

Answer (score 0):

`MvcSiteMapProvider` delegates the URL generation to the MVC `UrlHelper` class. This class in turn uses your routes to determine how to generate URLs. So, any changes you want to make to URLs should be done with routes. For this particular case, you need to add a custom route.

> **NOTE:** Routing does not deal with query string parameters. However, when generating URLs that you put undefined route values into, it will append their values to the query string. Do note that technically this doesn't count as "routing" - these parameters never are placed in the route value collection on incoming requests so they will be ignored by default by `MvcSiteMapProvider`. Unlike query string values, route values are not ignored by default so you must always take them into account.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Project",
            url: "project",
            defaults: new { controller = "Project", action = "Edit" }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Then your SiteMap configuration should be

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Contact" controller="Home" action="Contact"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Project" controller="Project" action="Index">
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Edit a Project" 
            controller="Project" action="Edit" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

You will then need to supply the `projectid` in order to get to the page via your own `ActionLink`.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit Project", "Edit", "Project", new { projectid = "12de8b10-aaae-ebbb-cccc-00215e466552" }, null)
```

Which will go to the URL `localhost/project/?projectid=12de8b10-aaae-ebbb-cccc-00215e466552`.